# Is $a\in[a,a)$?

Tags: real-analysis

The title is my question, no more things.

Comment: Without more context Readers willing to respond will have to guess at why this short post presents a problem of interest to you.  Use the body of the Question to share your thoughts:  how to apply the definition, where did the problem come up, what makes it interesting or challenging?

Answer (score 9):

$[a,b)$ is defined as $\{x:\ a\leq x < b\}$. If $a=b$ then the inequality $a\leq x < a$ is never satisfied. Therefore the set is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy , it's easy and your way explanation is brilliant

Answer (score 0):

No, as $[a,a)$ means $a \le a $ and $a<a$ according to Baby Rudin.  The second inequality is clearly false, so the set $[a,a)=\varnothing$.